# MAMP or Manual configurating everything on Mac

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mamp

I just thought to ask it here, to see what others think about it.

I personally installed MAMP two days ago, because I had so much troubles with installing and configurating everything on my MBP Retina.

I had problems with phpmyadmin and after 2 months I realised that I need to install mcrypt separately and when I wanted to upgrade php there's so much things to deal with...

I just couldnt stand all of this, so I think it is better to use MAMP then configurating all these.

Maybe I am wrong, maybe it is better to do all these manually?

Also what are differences? 
I think the only difference is that you depend on developers of MAMP to update it with latest php, mysql, apache... but no rush!

Sorry if it's double post, just couldn't find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would never use MAMP on OS X. Just use a package manager to install everything and then you can configure it. Though for the most part it will be set up out of the box. Well at least with macports anyway, which is what i use. There are also Fink and Homebrew. I've heard (this was some time ago) that Fink's packages lag so i dunno if id go that route. Alot of people sem to use Homebrew, but i dont like it because it works with the system software at and i prefer an isolated installation of everything. Thats really a preference thing though.

Also dont use phpmyadmin... Just use something like [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/).

Comment: Thanks for all these informations. I've used Sequel Pro once and it is great... I removed it only because I've got crazy in a momment.

About Fink's and Homebrew Packages, I have never heard about this. Gotta search for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right in what you said. The only difference is the version and special modules/addons/plugins that are used, e.g. PHP extensions and so on. Other than that there's no difference. If you do it manually then I recommend using homebrew.

Comment: All righty! Well thank you for your reply. As in reply of another answer I will need to checkout what is this "homebrew". :)